# Finding a new probability distribution from an expression

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

So in a Random Variables class, we were introduced to the Rician Distribution:
           $$f(z) = {z\over (\sigma_n)^2} * exp(-{(z^2 + a^2)\over 2(\sigma_n)^2}) * I_o({az\over \sigma_n^2})$$

where $I_o({az\over \sigma_n^2})$ is the zeroth order modified bessel function of the first kind and $\mathbf a$ is the magnitude of the uniform variable added to the original gaussian distribution.

Now I was wondering what distribution would result if we exchanged the zeroth order bessel function with a first order bessel function. I thought the new random variable would follow this expression:

$$Z = |\mathcal N + Ae^{i\theta} + Be^{i\phi}| $$ where $\mathcal N $ is a complex random variable with zero-mean and variance $= \sigma_n^2$, and $\theta$ and $\phi$ are uniform random variables over $[ 0, 2\pi]$ ( $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are just constant magnitudes)

Now when I started to solve the pdf for the above expression I hit a huge obstacle when I tried integrating out the phase of the new random variable i.e. 
$ \Psi  = tan^{-1} ({\mathcal {Im}(Z) \over \mathcal {Re} (Z)})$ from the transformed bivariate pdf

so using $z_r = \mathcal {Re}(Z) , z_c = \mathcal{Im} (Z)$

my first step was defining the new distribution

$$ f(z_r,  z_c| \theta, \phi) = (2\pi\sigma_n^2)^{-1} * exp (- {{[(z_r - a\cos\theta - b\cos\phi)^2 + (z_c - a\sin\theta - b\sin\phi)^2]}\over 2\sigma_n^2})$$

simple algebra changes the exponential expression $M(z_r , z_c, \theta, \phi)$ to

$$ M(z, \theta, \phi, \psi) = exp(-{{[z^2 + a^2 + b^2 -2az\cos(\psi - \theta) - 2bz\cos(\psi - \phi) + 2ab\cos(\theta -\phi)]}\over 2\sigma_n^2})$$
where $ z = \sqrt{z_r^2 + z_c^2}$ ( I have ignored the jacobian for now)

now we need to integrate $\psi$ out of the expression so we integrate $M$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Now the integral   $\mathcal I$ has the expression:

$$\mathcal I = \int_0^{2\pi} exp({{[az\cos(\psi - \theta) + bz\cos(\psi - \phi)]}\over \sigma_n^2})$$

Now I am stuck on how to integrate this expression, i tried by parts and the expression became very big and ugly and could not find a closed form to the result at all .

I was hoping someone could guide me in finding the right expression for such an integral.

Thanks

Comment: $I_0$ is the zero-eth order _modified_ Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: I have edited that sentence, thanks for noticing that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $I_{0}$ is changed by $I_{1}$ it is possible to obtain the following probability distribution

$$f \left( z \right) =2\,\sqrt {2}z{{\rm e}^{-{\frac {2\,{z}^{2}+{a
}^{2}}{{4\sigma_{{n}}}^{2}}}}}
{{I}_{1}\left({\frac {az}{{\sigma_{{n}}}^{2}}}\right)}{\frac {{a}^{-1}{\sigma_{{n}
}}^{-1} }{\sqrt {\pi }}}\left( 
{{I}_{0}\left({\frac {{a}^{2}}{{4\sigma_{{n}}}^{2}}}\right)}+
{{I}_{1}\left({\frac {{a}^{2}}{{4\sigma_{{n}}}^{2}}}\right)}
 \right) ^{-1}$$

Comment: Oh wow ok, but then what would the expression I had produce? as in what would the integral evaluate to?